# Return Var Value In User Message

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and I'm currently learning JavaScript. Sorry if my code is not the most readable ever :)

I'm using this function here to calculate mortgage values (messages and business rules are in Portuguese/Brazilian standards):

```
function calculaFinanc() {
  var amount1 = document.getElementById("amount1").value;
  var amount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
  var teto = (amount1 / 100) * 30;
  var parcela = amount2 / 360;
  if (Math.round(teto) < Math.round(parcela)) {
        return [document.getElementById("userMessage").className += 'alert alert-danger' , document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "<p>Voc&#234; n&#227;o pode financiar este im&#243;vel. O valor da parcela de seu financiamento n&#227;o poder&#225; ultrapassar 30&#37; valor da sua renda mensal</p>"];
    } else { //... rest omitted for brevity
```

Inside the `<p>` tag in the return statement, I'd like to display the value of variables "teto" and "parcela". How on earth do I do that? No matter what I tried, it doesn't show anything (or it just displays the text "teto").

e.g. this is how I'd like to return:

```
return [document.getElementById("userMessage").className += 'alert alert-danger' , document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "<p>Voc&#234; n&#227;o pode financiar este im&#243;vel. O valor da parcela de seu financiamento n&#227;o poder&#225; ultrapassar 30&#37; valor da sua renda mensal ($var_teto)</p>"];
```

Comment: hint: `.value` returns a string, not a `Number`.

Comment: return [document.getElementById("userMessage").className += 'alert alert-danger' , document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "<p>Voc&#234; n&#227;o pode financiar este im&#243;vel. O valor da"+ parcela+" de seu financiamento n&#227;o poder&#225; ultrapassar 30&#37; valor da sua renda mensal"+teto+"</p>"];

Comment: @DanielA.White I guess you say this because it would return anything the user had put into the form right? i.e. letters and symbols

I actually used another function to prevent other kind of characters inside the forms besides numbers. But I thank you for the input and will add this on my list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it into the string.

```
 return [document.getElementById("userMessage").className += 'alert alert-danger' , document.getElementById("userMessage").innerHTML = "<p>Voc&#234; n&#227;o pode financiar este im&#243;vel. O valor da parcela de seu financiamento n&#227;o poder&#225; ultrapassar 30&#37; valor da sua renda mensal "+teto+"</p>"];
```